# const reference behaviour - why this output?

Tags: c++

The following output is not clear to me. Why in the first case output is: Joni Gallo, while in the second case (after I changed only one line), output is: Jonlo

Output of this:

```
// classes and default constructors
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Example3 {
    string data;
  public:
        Example3 (const string& str) 
        {
            data = str;
           // data.erase(3,5);
        }

    Example3() {}
    void doit()
    {
    data.erase(3,5);
    }
    const string& content() const {return data;}
};

int main () {
  Example3 foo("Joni Gallo");
  Example3 bar (foo);
  bar.doit();
  cout << "content: " << foo.content() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

is `Joni Gallo`, while output of this:

```
// classes and default constructors
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Example3 {
    string data;
  public:
        Example3 (const string& str) 
        {
            data = str;
            data.erase(3,5);
        }

    Example3() {}
    void doit()
    {
   // data.erase(3,5);
    }
    const string& content() const {return data;}
};

int main () {
  Example3 foo("Joni Gallo");
  Example3 bar (foo);
  bar.doit();
  cout << "content: " << foo.content() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

is: `Jonlo`

? Why? Why erase affected the original object in the second case, but not in first?

PS Also what does passing `const string& str` in constructor and then assigning it to member variable mean - does it mean everytime I change the member variabe content the original objects contents (whose reference was passed to the constructor) will also be changed? (like it would be with pointers)

Comment: Well you `erase`'d in the original object's string in its constructor, so of course it modified it.

Comment: They are two different instances. In the first sample you change data in `bar` while you print `foo::data` that's unchanged. In the second case in `foo`constructor you change `data`.

Comment: @Jepessen: In the first case erase is called in constructor in the second case in function - that is the only difference. Why in first case original object is not changed and in the second case it is changed?

Comment: @Quentin: I don't understand your response, please look more carefully at the question.

Comment: In your second snippet `foo` erases its own string in its constructor.

Comment: In both your examples you erase the contents of data held by the instance, not the contents of the original string,  because your `data` variable is only initialized with the argument.

Comment: If you used a debugger, you could easily see what is happening.  Debuggers allow you to execute one statement at a time see values of variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I don't have it with me right now, that's it.

Comment: probably you have it even if you don't know. In Windows with visual studio you can easily debug. In Linux debugging is integrated in many IDE's and even if you don't use them you can use gdb. I don't know about OSX but I think that's something similiar.

Comment: @Jepessen: I did online compilation, so I don't have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that even though you pass the string by reference for construction, you declared it without reference as a member of the class. So every class instance will have its own string. When you assign a reference to a non-reference variable, a copy is made. If you then change the non-reference copy (here your data member variable) the reference is not changed.

In the first program you edit the data member in the doit member function. In the second one you do it in the constructor.

First program:

- foo is constructed with "Joni Gallo" set as data.
- bar is constructed with foo. So it also has "Joni Gallo" as data.
- Now you can do whatever you want with bar. It will not change the data of foo.
- So the result is still "Joni Gallo"

Second program:

- foo is constructed with "Joni Gallo" and the erase operation removes from position 3 with length 5. So the data member of foo is "Jonlo".
- Again, nothing what happens to bar will change foo's data member.
- So the result is "Jonlo".

In conclusion the result you observe has nothing to do with foo's member being modified because of a reference. You probably missed that the construction would affect both foo and bar.

Comment: @userq No, if you assign a reference to a non reference variable, a complete copy is made. It only works the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

In your first sample you change `bar` instance, so `foo` remain unchanged and the content is what you've put in constructor.

In the second case inside `Example3` constructor you perform some change that's reflected in `foo`. They are different object so modification to one does noe affect the other one.

Comment: `bar` does not do anything to `foo`. In your first sample `foo` constructor stores the string as is, and then print it. It does not care what `bar` does in the meanwhile. In your second sample again, it's `foo` itself that changes the string inside its constructor, and again `bar` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the timing of `data.erase`: in the second case it is done in the constructor of `foo`, and then the modified string is copied to `bar` by the copy constructor. Even if you comment out the declaration of `bar` and the call to `doIt` (which is no-op anyway) the same modified string would get printed.

In the first case, however, no erasure is done on `foo`'s `data` at all, so the original string gets printed. Again, the declaration of `bar` and the call to `doIt` can get commented, because `foo`'s `data` is disconnected from that of `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Global

```
string data;
```

Is a string. Not a reference to a string or a pointer to a string. Any strings assigned to data will be copied.

`data = string`: Copy.

`data = string reference`: copy.

`data = string pointer`: compiler error.

`data = char array`: copy.

`data = char pointer`: copy.

Assuming the char array and char pointer are properly terminated. If not, undefined behaviour.

## Source 1:

```
Example3 foo("Joni Gallo");
```

Makes foo. foo copies supplied string foo.data = "Joni Gallo".

```
Example3 bar (foo);
```

Makes bar. Bar copies foo, so it gets a copy of foo's copy of the source string. bar.data = "Joni Gallo".

```
bar.doit();
```

Erases part of bar's copy of the string. bar.data = "Jonlo".

```
cout << "bar's content: " << foo.content() << '\n';
```

Is a lie. This prints out foo's copy of the string.

## Source 2:

```
Example3 foo("Joni Gallo");
```

Makes foo. foo copies supplied string and erases part of the copy. foo.data = "Jonlo".

```
Example3 bar (foo);
```

Makes bar. Bar copies foo, so it gets a copy of foo's edited copy of the source string. bar.data = "Jonlo".

```
bar.doit();
```

Does nothing. bar.data = "Jonlo".

```
cout << "bar's content: " << foo.content() << '\n';
```

Is still a lie, but this time foo's copy and Bar's copy will be identical.